# Returning set but getting iterable

Tags: python, pycharm

Let's say I have a method that returns a set with the values of a dictionary:

```
class my_class:
      def __init__(self):
          self.my_dictionary: dict[int, str] = {1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 4: 'd'}
      def my_method(self) -> set[str]:
          return set(self.my_dictionary.values())
```

When I invoke this method as shown below:

```
my_object = my_class()
my_set: set[str] = my_object.my_method()
```

I get the below error:

```
Expected type 'set[str]', got 'Iterable' instead
```

Does anyone understand why this would happen?

Comment: Cannot reproduce with `mypy 0.930`.

Comment: The `values()` method returns an iterable, PyCharm doesn't realize that it materializes as a set of strings.

Comment: @MatsLindh do you know of any workaround to this?

Comment: Perhaps you could explicitly type-hint that the values of `my_dictionary` are always strings.

Comment: @khelwood Forgot to mention, I tried that.

Comment: Which version of PyCharm are you using (and which introspection are you seeing this from)? As far as I can see I can't reproduce it in 2022.1.

Comment: @MatsLindh I am using PyCharm 2021.3.3 (Professional Edition).  The IDE issues a warning, with the text for my_object.my_method() yellow. Perhaps it's just an issue I can ignore?

Comment: @MatsLindh I should also note that the implementation for my_class and invoking the method my_object.my_method() are in two separate modules.

Comment: Yes, you should be able to ignore the warning as long as it's only from PyCharm. If you want to get more feedback try to make a minimal, self-contained example that can be loaded in PyCharm.